# Java loadLibrary() cannot locate library after switching from 64 bit jdk to 32 bit

Tags: java, dll, jvm, loadlibrary

I am attempting to load a native library which accordingly loads an original dll. However on another computer running XP 32bit, it works fine. When executed on a win7 64 bit system it would fail to load. On the xp machine, the dll files could be in same directory as class files, however in order to not get a unsatisfied link error, i had to copy the files into the system32 folder. Then it gave an error stating that a 32bit dll cannot be loaded on a 64 bit process. I downloaded the 32 bit jdk and set the jdk in the project to load the 32 bit jdk. When that was complete i again got an Unsatisfied link error, and the files are still in system32 as well as next to the class files. I am confused as to why it would find the library  when using 64 bit jdk and will not in 32 bit jdk.

```
...
static {
    System.loadLibrary("K8055jni");
}
```

---

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no K8055jni in java.library.path
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary(ClassLoader.java:1860)
at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary0(Runtime.java:845)
at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(System.java:1084)
at K8055jni.<clinit>(K8055jni.java:50)
at Test.main(Test.java:4)
```

How do i get the 32 bit jdk to locate the same files?

Comment: did you try setting the "java.library.path" to include either the local directory or system32?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IF I understand your question and problem correctly, then you might try either of:

1. Windows 7 place your 32-bit DLLs into \Windows\SysWOW64 instead of \Windows\System32.  Oddly enough, under Win 7, System32 is for 64-bit binaries only.  See [this](http://www.samlogic.net/articles/32-64-bit-windows-folder-x86-syswow64.htm) and [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WoW64) for details.
2. Better still, place your binary files in an application folder, and specify on the java command line:

   `-Djava.library.path=<path-to-dll-lib>`

Comment: Thanks for the help. The first option worked first try. Makes sense why it couldn't find the file.