# How to fix java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError-Problem with 64-bit / 32-bit Systems?

Tags: java, dll

I hava a 64-bit System and want want to run a Java-Application that needs to load a 32-bit dll-file. I want to load the libary using ***System.load()***. When using a 64-bit Java-8-JRE the following error occurs:

```
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: C:\[...]\test.dll: Can't load IA 32-bit .dll on a AMD 64-bit platform.
```

When running the application on a 32-bit Java-6-JRE it sais

```
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: C:\[...]\test.dll: Can't find dependent libraries
```

I tried to use a 64-bit version of Java. Because the dll is a 32-bit dll I tried to run the application on a 64-bit-version. But then another error occures.

I also tried to use ***System.loadLibrary()*** instead. But the errors seem to be similar.

Java-8-64-bit:

```
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: C:\Windows\System32\test.dll: Can't load IA 32-bit .dll on a AMD 64-bit platform
```

--> Because of this error I can be sure java is able to find this file in general.

Java-6-32-bit:

```
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no test in java.library.path
```

--> Because of the error shown before the file have to be there.

My code of the application is very short:

Using ***System.load()***:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.load("C:\\[...]\\test.dll");
}
```

Using ***System.loadLibary()***:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.loadLibrary("test");
}
```

The file has all necessary permissions.

The typical error that the file is not in the PATH can be excluded because running a 64-bit-JVM the file can be found but can not be read because it needs a 32-bit JVM.

Has anybody any ideas? Thanks!

Comment: Have you checked the java library path on the 32bits JVM?

Comment: Why do I need to check the java library path when not using System.loadLibrary()? I am using System.load(). Then I don't have to use the java library path, do I?

Comment: And when I print the Library path using System.out.println(System.getProperty("java.library.path")); I get the same result on 64- and 32-bit jvm.

Comment: Refer this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29394163/cant-load-ia-32-bit-dll-on-a-amd-64-bit-platform?rq=1, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19518304/jmvfw-dll-cant-load-ia-32-bit-dll-on-a-amd-64-bit-platform?noredirect=1&lq=1 I guess you will get some help.

Comment: This does not help me.. I allready installed a 32-bit version and inclueded it into eclipse like I said in my question. The refered thread just tells me to do this?!

Comment: any dependency dll needed for "test.dll"?

Comment: I do not know the content of the dll in detail. But I guess that it include other dependencies regarding the error-message "Can't find dependent libraries".
I found In another thread the solution to move the files from the System32-folder to the parent-windows folder because the system32 folder just contais 64-binaries. Reference: https://stackoverflow.com/a/12307577/11011623

Answer (score 0):

The solution is very simple...

Regarding the thread https://stackoverflow.com/a/12307577/11011623 the System32-folder, where my file and my dependencies have been, just allows 64-bit-binaries to be in it. So the 32-bit-dll was not found. When using System.load() and the dll at another path the system was not able to locate the necessary dependencies in the dll because the path where the dll is, is not part of the path...

Solution was to move all necessary files from System32 to Windows folder or to add a custom folder with all dlls and its dependencies to the PATH.
Thanks for all comments that helped solving this problem.